# Pass array of structs from Python to C

Tags: python, python-3.x, structure, python-c-api

**[Update: Problem solved! See bottom of the post]**

I need to allow python developers to pass an array of packed data (in this case vertices) into my API, which is a series of C++ interfaces exposed manually through the Python C API. My initial impression with this is to use the ctypes Structure class to allow for an interface like this:

```
class Vertex(Structure):
_fields_ = [
    ('x', c_float),
    ('y', c_float),
    ('z', c_float),
    ('u', c_float),
    ('v', c_float),
    ('color', c_int)
] 

verts = (Vertex * 3)()
verts[0] = Vertex(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0xFF0000FF)
verts[1] = Vertex(0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, -0.5, 0x00FF00FF)
verts[2] = Vertex(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, -0.5, -0.5, 0x0000FFFF)

device.ReadVertices(verts, 3) # This is the interfaces to the C++ object
```

Where the function I'm trying to pass to has the following signature:

```
void Device::ReadVertices(Vertex* verts, int count);
```

And the Python wrapper looks something like this:

```
static PyObject* Device_ReadVertices(Py_Device* self, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject* py_verts;
    int count;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Oi", &py_verts, &count)) 
        return NULL;

    // This Doesn't Work!
    Vertex* verts = static_cast<Vertex*>(PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(py_verts));

    self->device->ReadVertices(verts, count);

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Of course, the biggest issue I have is this: I can retrieve the PyObject for the struct, but I have no idea how I would cast it to the correct type. The above code fails miserably. So how exactly would I go about allowing the user to pass me this kind of data from Python?

Now, a couple of things to consider: First is that I already have quite a bit of my Python/C++ layer written, and am perfectly happy with it (I moved away from SWIG so I could have more flexibility). I don't want to re-code it, so I would prefer a solution that works with the C API natively. Second, I do intend to have the Vertex structure be pre-defined in my C++ code, so I would prefer to not have the user need to re-define it in the Python (cuts down on errors that way), but I'm not sure how to expose a contiguous structure like that. Third, I have no reason for trying the ctypes structure aside from not knowing another way to do it. Any suggestions are welcome. Finally, since this is (as you may have guessed) for a graphics app I would prefer a faster method over a convenient one, even if the faster method takes a little bit more work.

Thanks for any help! I'm still feeling my way around python extensions, so it's a great help to get community input on some of the stickier parts.

**[SOLUTION]**

So first off, thanks to everyone who pitched in their ideas. It was a lot of little tidbits that added up to the eventual answer. In the end here is what I found: Sam's suggestion of using struct.pack ended up being right on the money. Seeing that I'm using Python 3, I had to tweak it ever so slightly, but when all was said and done this actually got a triangle showing up on my screen:

```
verts = bytes()
verts += struct.pack("fffffI", 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0xFF0000FF)
verts += struct.pack("fffffI", 0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, -0.5, 0x00FF00FF)
verts += struct.pack("fffffI", -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, -0.5, -0.5, 0x0000FFFF)

device.ReadVertices(verts, 3)
```

With my tuple parsing now looking like this:

```
static PyObject* Device_ReadVertices(Py_Device* self, PyObject* args)
{
    void* py_verts;
    int len, count;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y#i", &py_verts, &len, &count)) 
        return NULL;

    // Works now!
    Vertex* verts = static_cast<Vertex*>(py_verts);

    self->device->ReadVertices(verts, count);

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Note that even though I don't use the `len` variable in this example (though I will in the final product) I need to parse the tuple using 'y#' instead of just 'y' or else it will stop at the first NULL (according to the documentation). Also to be considered: void* casts like this are quite dangerous, so please do loads more error checking than I show here!

So, job well done, happy day, pack up and go home, yes?

Wait! Not so fast! There's MORE!

Feeling good about how that all worked out I decided, on a whim, to see if my previous attempt still blew up on me and reverted back to the first snippet of python in this post. (Using the new C code, of course) and... it worked! The results were identical to the struct.pack version! Wow!

So this means your users have a choice in how they're going to provide this kind of data, and your code can handle either with no changes. Personally I'm going to encourage the ctype.Structure method, since I think it makes for easier readability, but really it's whatever the user is comfortable with. (Heck, they could manually type out a string of bytes in hex if they wanted to. It works. I tried.)

Honestly I think this is the best possible outcome, so I'm ecstatic. Thank you all again, and good luck to anyone else who runs into this problem!

Comment: have you considered using boost::python?

Comment: Yes, I tried it before I tried SWIG. I found SWIG to be easier to use (very little additional code and you don't have to compile the monstrosity that is boost) with about the same performance. In the end, though, I wanted more control than SWIG gave me (for example, SWIG give you no way to expose Python properties) and so opted for to do the wrapper by had, which actually turned out to be quite painless once you get the basics down, not to mention my code is now much faster. :)

Comment: Granted, they're both fine libraries for those who don't want to lean the C-API. They just didn't suit my needs.

Comment: sure, point taken.  can try reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I doubt that's the root of the issue. I think that I need to drill through one more layer of abstraction before I get to the actual pointer, but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Try the pack() and unpack() methods? http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

Comment: I've seen that a couple of times. Couldn't quite wrap my head around how I might use it in this kind of scenario. How would you go about it?

Comment: Does your Vertex type in C++ code need to be an object or can it be a C struct?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but it's possible to use ctypes for that? i thought they were only for calling dynamic libraries.

Comment: Yes. Yes it is, apparently. :) See my updates above for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but you should give this a try and let us know if its fast enough for your needs.

On the python side, pack the vertices into a string instead of an object.

```
str = "" # byte stream for encoding data
str += struct.pack("5f i", vert1.x, vert1.y, vert1.z, vert1.u, vert1.v, vert1.color) # 5 floats and an int
# same for other vertices

device. ReadVertices( verts, 3) # send vertices to C library
```

On the C library/python wrapper, modify your PyArgs_ParseTuple to use the format string `"si"`. This will convert your python string into a C string (char*) which you can then typecast as a pointer to your vector struct. At this point the C string is a stream of bytes/words/floats and should be what you're looking for.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. A little bit clunkier than I was hoping, but I'll try it out!

Comment: Yeah, its not the niftiest solution... but its pretty language agnostic, and C really is low level enough for this to actually work. Hope this helps!

Comment: Well go figure, not only did this work but it also showed me how to get my first approach working as well! Yay! Thank you very much, and see my updates above for the details.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I can see to do would be to just avoid the issue altogether and expose a Device_ReadVertex that takes in x, y, z, u, v and color as arguments.  This has obvious drawbacks, like making the Python programmers feed it vertices one by one.

If that's not good enough (seems likely it isn't), then you could try defining a new Python type as described [here](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html).  It's a bit more code but I think this is the "more architecturally sound" method, because you ensure your Python developers are using the same type definition as you are in the C code.  It also allows for a bit more flexibility than a simple struct (it's really a class, with the potential to add methods, etc), which I'm not sure you actually need but it might come in handy later.

Comment: I'm currently defining about 10 or so new types as part of my API, so that's not a problem for me. The question is really how the user could feed me that information as a contiguous array (especially since with the python types you have to have the type header overhead for every instance.)

Comment: Ah, I see.  You care a lot about the space usage as well as the CPU usage, right?  I think the struct answer Sam Post gives below is as space efficient as you will get but from my experience the struct module tends to use a lot of CPU to pack and unpack.  It seems like you might be on the best track with the ctype Structure.  I'll look around to see if I can't figure out why your structure isn't coming through properly.

Comment: I kind of have to care about the space, since this is data that is intended to be passed to DirectX or OpenGL. While you can get away with non-tightly packed data there, it's best if you don't because otherwise you'll just be filling your video memory with junk data. As for why the struct isn't coming through, I've got that solved. I'll update the question in a moment.